# validation summary appearance

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, validation

i have three buttons on the form (Add,Delete, and Reset)..

and required field validators .when click on add button and those fields are empty , the validation summary shows the messages .and then when click on delete button or reset button the validation summary still exist (although the Cause validation property for these button is false )what is the problem ?? i wanna the validation summary appeared only with the (add button) to prevent any confusion to my user.. how to clear the validation summary or control the appearance of it for the(add button only)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find type of answer..i use callout validator extender in stead of the summary validation 
..
i think it fixes my probelm.
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx..